# Excluded Regions in Jenkins with Git

Tags: git, continuous-integration, jenkins

I have a git repository where I have created two different jobs in Jenkins (one for production code and one for tools). Where both jobs always are triggered!

I have added Excluded Regions for each jobs to only trigger on each correct folder.

Our git root folder contains the following:

```
/src/
/tools/
/test/
/doc/
/third party/
```

In my Source job in Jenkins I have the following Excluded Regions

```
/tools/.*
/Test Projects/.*
/doc/.*
```

In my tools job I have the folling Excluded Regions

```
/src/.*
/Test Projects/.*
/doc/.*
```

The problem is that if I push a change in doc-folder both jobs are triggered. I don't have any include regions either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This setup should work.

However if you are using [Gerrit Triggers](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) in Jenkins the exclude/include regions in GitSCM plugin will not work. In the Gerrit Trigger plugin there is an option to add file paths which will work like an include region, i.e. the build will only get triggered when there is a change in the file path added.

In the Gerrit trigger configuration of your job add a file path like below to include tools directory.

Path   tools/**

Comment: I just met the same issue, and I have configured the file path in gerrit trigger configuration. But ridiculously, it just can't work. Other commits not in the specific file path also triggered the build. Do you have any idea about it? Thanks!

Comment: @Nancy Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm stuck at the same boat as you. Just can't get the file path to work.

Comment: @MarkusLindberg Sorry, I haven't got the solution. Bad news, we just turned back to poll SCM in some case.

Comment: @Nancy Okay, that's a shame. Thanks for the reply though, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

My fix for this using Git plugin in jenkins is :

1. Put path relative to GIT_ROOT.
2. Append a cap ^ before the path in include/exclude regions.
   Example : `^pollme/.*` where pollme is the first folder under git repo heirarchy.
3. Enable  "Force polling using workspace" under Additional Behaviors in git plugin in jenkins.

Works perfectly for me after applying above options.