# Jenkins not excluding certain folders in excluded regions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have setup a CI Workflow in Jenkins to build project from bitbucket server.

I followed this [Excluded Regions in Jenkins with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211227/excluded-regions-in-jenkins-with-git)

I made configuration such that ,when ever any changes are pushed into the repository, Jenkins will trigger a build.
I felt Repository is having too many checkins and each project is having separate workflows in Jenkins. So I used the **"Polling ignores commits in certain places" option**
But it seems not working.
I think this may be a bug as well.
Please see screenshot attached.

**Scenario**
I have 3 projects named Project1,Project2 and Project3

I want to look only changes in Project1 and then build.
For that i gave "Project1/.*" in the Included Regions. But even when changes are done to Project2 / Project 3, Jenkins triggers a build.

**Doubt:**
**The Repository structure is as below

Project : TestForJenkins

    Repository : JenkinsRepo

               Project1,Project2,Project3,Packages,.gitignore**

Since Project1 is at toplevel in repository, please let me know if i am giving wrong lookup path by providing "Project1/.*" in included region section.

[image]

Comment: where is the screenshot attached?

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi  : Thanks . I edited the original post to include screenshot.